# Downgrade php version on debian

Tags: debian, php, version

I have a big problem with my sites after I migrated to a new server.
The only difference is the php version.
On the old server I have `5.3.3-7+squeeze15` and on the new server there is `5.3.3-7+squeeze17`.

Can I downgrade to the older version? If so then how?

The distro I'm using is Debian Squeeze 6.0.8.

Comment: BTW, do not crosspost! [Debian: downgrade php version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20349507)

Comment: You can generally get older versions from snapshot.debian.org.

Answer (score 4):

Remove existing PHP and then re-install PHP version of choice as below:

```
apt-get install pkg_name=version
```

Also, You can list available version as :

```
apt-cache showpkg pkg_name
```

Comment: Does this really work? Old versions of packages are available? How can remote available versions be listed (I'm often storage constrained and then forced to clean the package cache)?

Comment: @uprego Old versions of packages are available from snapshot.debian.org.

Comment: It may happen that this version is no longer installable, in which case you'd need to fetch it from the [snapshot service](http://snapshot.debian.org/), and install it via dpkg:

`sudo dpkg --install <deb filename>`